# Accessing an element within my custom linked list class

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm building my own linked list class and I'm having some issues figuring out how to write some functions to help me traverse this list. This is my first time building a linked list from scratch, so if my approach is unconventional please let me know what might be more conventional.

I'd like write a function, within the List class that allows me to increment to the next element called getNext() as well as one that getPrev();

I wrote getNext like this:

```
T* getNext(){return next;}
```

However it tells me next is not declared within the scope. I'd also like to write a function that lets me access and modify the object within the list. I was considering using the bracket operator, but first I need to write a function to return the data member. Perhaps If I take a similar approach as I did within my pop functions.. thinking about it now. However, I'd still appreciate any advice.

Here is my List class:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H


//List Class
template <class T>
class List{
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        //Constructs Node Element
        Node(T t, Node* p, Node* n) { data = (t); prev = (p); next = (n); }
//      T *getNext() {return next;}
    };
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
public: 
    //Constructor
    List() { head = NULL; tail=NULL; }
    //Destructor
    ~List() { 
        while(head){
            Node * temp(head);
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    //is empty
    bool empty() const {return (!head || !tail ); }
    operator bool() const {return !empty(); }
    //Push back
    void push_back(T data) {
        tail = new Node(data, tail, NULL);
        if(tail->prev) //if the node in front of tail is initilized
            tail->prev->next = tail;

        if( empty() )
            head = tail;
    }
    //Push front
    void push_front(T data) {
        head = new Node(data, NULL, head);
        if(head->next)//if the node following head is initilized
            head->next->prev = head;

        if( empty() )
         tail = head;
    };
    T pop_back() {
        if( empty() )
            throw("Error in List: List is empty\n");

        Node* temp(tail);
        T data(tail->data);
        tail = tail->prev;

        if( tail )
            tail->next = NULL;
        else
            head = NULL;

        delete temp;
        return data;
    }
    T pop_front() {
        if (empty())
            throw("Error in List: List is empty\n");

        Node* temp(head);
        T data(head->data);
        head = head->next;

        if(head)
            head->prev=NULL;
        else
            tail = NULL;

        delete temp;
        return data;
    }

    T getNext(){return next;}
};


#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`getNext` should be part of the `struct Node` and return a `Node*`

```
Node* getNext() { return next; }
```

Then from that you can get the value.

If you have to have it part of the `list` itself, which I would not recommend it will need to take a parameter of what `Node` you would like the `next` of:

```
Node* getNext(Node* n) {return n->next;}
```

Again, I recommend the first option.

Here is an approximate whole class with both of these:

```
template<typename T>
class List {
  public:
    struct Node {
      Node* next, prev;
      T data;

      //some constructor and stuff

      Node* Next() {return next;}
    }

    //some constructors and other functions

    Node* getNext(Node* _n) {return _n->Next();}
}
```

then to use:

```
int main() {
  List<int> l;
  //add some stuff to the list
  //get the head of the list
  List<int>::Node* head = l.head; //or some corresponding function

  //then
  List<int>::Node* next = head->Next();
  //or
  List<int>::Node* next2 = l.getNext(head);
}
```

Comment: The first argument makes sense logically, And to call it from list, I tried to do something like this: `Node* getNext(){ return Next(); }//within list` And When I try it the second way, It outputs that "class List<int> has no member named getNext()"

Comment: this is probably because you say `Next()` and that has no object associated with it. If you notice in my second approach the function needs an argument.

Comment: I had tried using the second method, however this error happened when I tired to compile: `no matching function for call to âList<CLASSNAME>::getNext()â
`

Comment: Also, to clarify the `Next()` call. The `next` member of the struct was outputing as being `out of the scope` so I made function like this to try and fix that within the node struct `Node* Next() { return next;}` However that had a similar error.

Comment: Ah ok, the no matching function call to the list error is because you must provide a parameter to `List::getNext`...e.g., `myList.getNext(myNode)`. Again I will reiterate that the second idea is NOT the way to go. and you should simply stick with the first, as you have with `Next`

Answer (score 0):

for starters `getNext()` should not return a pointer to the template class, it should return a pointer to the `Node` structure.

So it should be

```
Node* getNext(){return next;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a member of `Node` struct and `getNext` is member of `List`. You should access it from an object of type `Node`.