# Accessing Linked List private variable from outside class

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, private-members

I am currently working on a program that will access a linked list written by another person. I'm assuming this person will have declared the head and tail variables as private, but I would like to iterate through their linked list.

Here is a possible linked list implementation

```
/* singly linked list node */
struct SLLNode {
    int data;
    SLLNode *next;
};

/* singly linked list implementation */
class SLinkedList {
public:
    SLinkedList();
    ~SLinkedList();

    void addToTail(int newData);
    void addToHead(int newData);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const SLinkedList&);

private:
    SLLNode *head;
    SLLNode *tail;
};
```

I would like to access the pointer to the head in order to be able to iterate through the linked list.

How can I access that pointer without being able to change the nodes? Not being able to change simply for safety. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not believe you should expose this implementation detail outside of the SLinkedList. Instead provide a way to iterate over your list so other classes have access to the elements but not the inner implementation of SLinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it is private.

The other person needs to provide access to you, with a public member function for example.

As for an example, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387577/accessing-an-element-within-my-custom-linked-list-class) question.

Comment: Then I guess my other question is what public member can I write that will return a pointer in which the data can not be changed.

Comment: But the class is not yours, are you allowed to do so? It depends on what you want. You can't return a const reference for example of the pointer. Bur probably that's another question.

Comment: You're right. I'm simply using this for testing right now, but I understand a lot better now, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @Justin. Remember that private is there to ensure that nobody outside the class has direct access to private fields.

Comment: I also included a link. Nice question by the way, +1. @Justin

Answer (score 1):

It is the person who designed this list has to provide an interface that you could access data stored in the list.

Now you can only add data to the list and output them all.

Usually such containers provide iterators that allow to traverse the list. 
The person should write such an interface. Otherwise there is no any usefulness of the list.